# How to replace null values in a dataframe based on values in other dataframe?

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Here's a dataframe, `df1`, I have

```
+---------+-------+---------+
|   C1    |   C2  |   C3    |
+---------+-------+---------+
|    xr   |   1   |   ixfg  |
|    we   |   5   |   jsfd  |
|    r5   |   7   |   hfga  |
|    by   |   8   |   srjs  |
|    v4   |   4   |   qwks  |
|    c0   |   0   |   khfd  |
|    ba   |   2   |   gdbu  |
|    mi   |   1   |   pdlo  |
|    lp   |   7   |   ztpq  |
+---------+-------+---------+
```

Here's another, `df2`, that I have

```
+----------+-------+---------+
|    V1    |   V2  |   V3    |
+----------+-------+---------+
|    Null  |   6   |   ixfg  |
|    Null  |   2   |   jsfd  |
|    Null  |   2   |   hfga  |
|    Null  |   7   |   qwks  |
|    Null  |   1   |   khfd  |
|    Null  |   9   |   gdbu  |
+----------+-------+---------+
```

What I would like to have is another dataframe that

1. Ignores values in V2 and takes values in C2 whereever V3 and C3 match, and
2. Replaces V1 with values in C1 wherever V3 and C3 match.

The result should look like the following:

```
+----------+-------+---------+
|    M1    |   M2  |   M3    |
+----------+-------+---------+
|    xr    |   1   |   ixfg  |
|    we    |   5   |   jsfd  |
|    r5    |   7   |   hfga  |
|    v4    |   4   |   qwks  |
|    c0    |   0   |   khfd  |
|    ba    |   2   |   gdbu  |
+----------+-------+---------+
```

Answer (score 1):

You can `join` and use `coalesce` to take a value which has a higher priority.

** `coalesce` will take any number of columns (the highest priority to least in the order of arguments) and return first non-null value, so if you do want to replace with null when there is a null in the lower priority column, you cannot use this function.

```py
df = (df1.join(df2, on=(df1.C3 == df2.V3))
      .select(F.coalesce(df1.C1, df2.V1).alias('M1'), 
              F.coalesce(df2.V2, df1.C2).alias('M2'), 
              F.col('C3').alias('M3')))
```

Comment: `coalesce()` was very helpful. I have been doing `when(df.c.isNull(),...)`; but this is much simpler. ++ for that.